# What is the meaning of the time evolution of a product of coherent states of the QHO?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution, coherent-states

I am trying to analyze the dynamics of a coupled quantum harmonic oscillator (cQHO) system. The Hamiltonian of the system is given by:

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{Coupled}=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{j}\hat{p}_{j}^{2}+m^{2}{\Omega_j}^{2}(\hat{x}_{j+1}-\hat{x}_{j})^{2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Where $\Omega_j\equiv\sqrt{\frac{k_{j}}{m}}$.

Taking inspiration from *Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur* Chapter 2 (ISBN-13 978-0199699339) with a coordinate transformation $\hat{x}_{j}\rightarrow\sum_{k}{X}_{k}e^{ikja}$ and $\hat{p}_{j}\rightarrow\sum_{k}{P}_{k}e^{ikja}$ where $P_{k}$ and $X_{k}$ are the normal coordinates and $a$ is the equilibrium distance between the  oscillating particles/masses, the author shows that the Hamiltonian can be uncoupled into:

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{Normal}=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{k}P_{k}^2+m^{2}{\omega}_{k}^{2}X_k^2\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Where $\omega_{k}$ is the $k^{th}$ classical normal mode eigenfrequency of the system. In other words, the system can be treated as  a system of uncoupled oscillators and solved that way. The solution for the ground state of this system, I believe, is simply:

\begin{equation}
\Psi_{0}(X_1
,X_2,X_3,...t)=\psi_{0}(X_1,t)\otimes\psi_{0}(X_2,t)\otimes\psi_{0}(X_3,t)...\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Where $\psi_{0}(X_k,t)$ is simply the ground state wave function of the $k^{th}$ harmonic oscillator where $x{\rightarrow}X_{k}$ and $\omega{\rightarrow}\omega_{k}$.

I'm interested in the case of a finite number of such oscillators, all of which are in a coherent state. I would like to understand the dynamics of such a state but I can't find any previous work on the topic. The wave function of a coherent state of the harmonic oscillator is:

\begin{equation}
\phi_{\alpha}(x,t)=Ae^\frac{Q^2}{2}e^{\frac{-i{\omega}t}{2}}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}({\alpha}e^{i{\omega}t}-\sqrt{2}Q)^2]\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Where $A\equiv{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_{0}{\sqrt{\pi}}}}}$, $x_{0}\equiv\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}$,$Q\equiv\frac{x}{x_{0}}$, and $\alpha$ is the eigenvalue associated to the action of the annihilation operator on the coherent state, or equivalently $\alpha\equiv\frac{S}{2x_{0}}$ where S is the arbitrary displacement associated to the displacement operator $D(\alpha)\equiv{\exp(\frac{i\hat{p}S}{\hbar})}=\exp[\alpha^{\star}\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\alpha\hat{a}]$.

As far as I can tell, the total wave function of the coupled oscillator system in the normal mode coordinates is still just given by the tensor product over these states:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_{\alpha}(X_1,X_2,X_3...X_N,t)=\prod_{n}^{N}\phi_{\alpha_{n}}(X_n,t)\tag{5}
\end{equation}

Which we can also write as:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_{\alpha}(X_1,X_2,...,t)=\mathcal{A}e^{H(x,t)}\\H(x,t)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{Q_{k}^{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\omega_{k}t+(\alpha_{k}e^{i{\omega}_{k}t}-\sqrt{2}Q_{k})^2\\\mathcal{A}\equiv\prod_{k}A_{k}\tag{6}
\end{equation}

If I choose arbitrary values of $X_1,X_2,X_3...$ such that $X_k=\alpha_{k}$ and plot the function, with the choice to make $N=6$, I get: [image]

This shape is periodic with large regions of zero in between as seen here:

[image]

I don't quite understand how this structure arises, what it means, or if it has any physical meaning at all. Why does the time evolution look like this? I get that it is a product of Gaussian packets which each evolve in time like plane waves about the mean.

I wish I could be a bit more clear about what I'm asking here, but it is simply my goal to understand this time-dependent behavior of the set of oscillators on a deeper level than I do right now. I would also like if I could know what the Fourier transform of this state is but it seems no one has tried to tackle that question.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction and help me out to understand this better?